# If a string had mass in an Atwood machine, would the objects be at rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, string, equilibrium

So I understand that the tension produced by a string in an Atwood Machine is constant throughout the string assuming it is ideal, but what if it wasn't? Wouldn't there be a tension gradient, in which the net force acting on both masses would be zero? I was thinking that because the tension in the string would vary on either side of the machine, because the string would become taut enough to support both masses, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: This is a standard problem at the level of upper-division mechanics or engineering dynamics. It can be solved with techniques introduced in the intro class, but requires differential equation once the problem is reduced to math.

Comment: Would it not be static because realistically there would be friction between the pulley and the string?

Comment: You seem to be mixing several concepts. Start from physical reality here. You can do demonstrations of these systems; those demonstrations use strings with mass and they don't  always hang there statically. Right? I mean they *can*, if the pulley isn't very good, or if you are using a slip channel instead of a actual pulley, but they don't *have to*. So any understanding tells you "[this idea] has to make it be static" is wrong. Now go looking for the issue.

Comment: But ... can you follow the application of physical law and the math for solving these systems all the way through. I see a lot of misconceptions in these system when people try to intuit their way through instead of applying the tools long-hand. (This is a system that often trips up students who've been relying on raw intelligence and doesn't phase students who've had to work at "easier" problems because the process just works; lesson: learn the process, you're going to need it eventually.)

Comment: I guess it would not be static because there would be a net force acting on the string , which would act in the direction of the heavier object.

Comment: Your guess is wrong in general, because if the string has mass the weight of the string (distributed along its length) is another force acting on the string. As the other comments said, you have to follow "the process", not guess!